# Pass multiple bit values of enum class to function

Tags: c++, enums, bit

I can't figure our how to pass multiple bit values of enum class and check them inside function.
I have the following code:

```
enum class BitFlags
{
    Write,
    Read,
    NumOfFlags
};

void update(BitFlags flags)
{
    // Figure out if Write and Read flags are set
}
```

Trying to make

```
update(BitFlags::Read | BitFlags::Write);
```

does not work. Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Enum class might not be the best choice here. You need to explicitly cast everything to int first.

Comment: The enum class can only have one value, thus you can't have Read and Write at the same time in your case.  (It can't be used to contain a bit pattern)

Comment: emum class is more appropriate as a state variable in a state machine where you can only be in one state at a time.  If you only have several values, you could combine (read, read_write, write)